# When to use JPA/EJB and JSF when building apps in oracle adf

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I need some inputs on ADF framework and application/project types. I am re-writing an existing Oracle Forms 6 application to a Java J2EE Application. I am exploring Oracle ADF framework along with other framworks such as struts 2 with jsf and sping & hibernate with jsf.

Here are the requirements of my new application.

- 3 tier architecture application
- Need rich UI functionality such as dynamic tables, charts, file export from tables etc..
- Use existing database tables to view, edit and save data
- Flexbile design to change, edit, or add new pages and business logic
- Support business rules
- Flexibility to add expose some of the business services as web services
- Support crud operations on large database tables
- Support https using oid and ldap

I have couple of questions.

1) Do you recommend Oracle ADF?

2) Does oracle ADF framework support all the above requirements?

3) I found tutorials for "Developing with Oracle ADF" and "Oracle ADF with JPA/EJB and JSF" on Oracle's site. Which one suits better for my needs? When to use JPA/EJB in ADF application?

Any insight on the above is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One benefit of ADF is it's one integrated product and all the pieces are designed to fit and work together with the tooling built into and supported by JDeveloper. No real setup or having to "make things work together." It simply does, OOTB.
The other solutions will require some "piecing together" to a greater or lesser degree. ADF is completely integrated from data source - RDB, WS, POJO, EJB, whatever, to UI. 
Also, any 3rd party fwk you use is going to cause tie-in.
ADF ties you to Java, but this is not as strong a tie-in as Forms which uses proprietary PL/SQL.

ADF Faces is based on, but extends JSF, which is hardly 90's technology, having been introduced in 2004. Also, it can easily be used with JS libs as needed. I suggest you look at the ADF success [stories](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/community/index-085291.html). Oracle built their entire new set of Business Apps using ADF. They literally bet the company on it. Doubt they would have done that with second class, substandard technology.

Tooling support is better for ADF BC than JPA - but either can be used. Also, ADF Faces supports development and deployment to either iOS or Android from the same UI design. Not sure there is any other fwk that can say that.
And yes, ADF supports all your requirements.
And ADF essentials, hosted on community edition glassfish, is free.

This [link](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_business_components_or_top) talks to: JPA or ADF BC.

Comment: Thanks Joe. This is what I was looking for. Does ADF suffice my requirements and if yes what to pick from ADF BC (BC4J) vs EJB/JPA.

Comment: I also found this http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2012/03/26/adf-11g-bc4j-or-ejb3/. In our case the primary key relations are not well defined on the tables of the old forms based app. There are 30 some forms with complex business rules and validation. Do you recommend ADF BC over JPA?

Comment: depends on the developer background. ADF BC was designed for 4gl developers who don't know java, basically - Forms, Siebel, PPsoft. JPA is for those who understand java and are ok working in classes and collections and OQL, IMHO. I'm good with both and in some ways JPA is easier for me and *possibly* faster since it sits on toplink community edition. BUT, the tooling support is better for ADF BC, BC is what Fusion Apps is written in and once one "gets it" has a lot mor support for validation, LOVs, and complex models.

Comment: Also, migrating DB changes up into the model layer is far easier and "automagical" than JPA. BC has support to synchronize the db structure with the BC model. Assuming no widespread root structural db changes- migration into the Model and then into the Data control and onto the page is all declarative, all automatic and very fast. like minutes fast. Not sure same can be said for JPA. If you are going down ADF path look at the add links on my site I give out to my students.

Comment: Good place to start: https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/Home/adf-links and https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/adf-information-sources/adf-links. Lots of good stuff there to get you started. Plus Oracle will be here . Can the same be said for other 3rd party add on vendors?

Comment: look at links here for migrating Forms to ADF: https://sites.google.com/site/joeztechland/Home/forms2adf Also look at jHeadstart. There's a Huge community out here to turn to for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

> 3 tier architecture application

Any Java EE or Spring based app will satisfy this.  Spring will force you to layer your application well.

> Need rich UI functionality such as dynamic tables, charts, file export
>   from tables etc..

You're more likely to get these using UI form elements from jQuery, d3 and other JavaScript based libraries.  Framework won't restrict your choices there.

> Use existing database tables to view, edit and save data

JDBC or anything built on top of it (JPA, Hibernate, etc.) will make this possible.

> Flexible design to change, edit, or add new pages and business logic

No framework will make this easy.  You'll have to get a shovel and do the work regardless.

> Support business rules

You can express business rules in many ways: code, state machines, Rete rules engines.  Which one do you want?

> Flexibility to add expose some of the business services as web
>   services

You can do this regardless of framework choice.  Spring has nice contract first, xsd-based web service remoting.

> Support crud operations on large database tables

Large is immaterial.  JDBC allows CRUD.

> Support https using oid and ldap

I don't see what HTTPS has to do with LDAP.

Your questions don't suggest a senior Java guy to me.

I would not recommend either Struts or JSF.  Both are 90s technology that aren't suited for mobile platforms.  The world is moving towards HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript.  I'd suggest that you do so, too.

If you want to use Spring I'd stick with their web MVC.  It's superior to both Struts and JSF, and you get all the other good stuff that Spring offers (e.g. DI and AOP).

Personally I think the fixation on Oracle ADF is too strong.  It ties you in just as much as Oracle Forms once did.

I'd think about this in terms of web services, REST or SOAP, and flexible UIs.  Decouple the front and back ends completely.  UIs come and go, but a good service model for your business processes, at the right level of granularity, will stand up for a while.

Comment: Thanks. Have you implemented any Oracle ADF apps? I found out from my research that all most all my requirements can be met using ADF. I was hoping to find someone sharing their experience implementing in ADF, specially large and data driven apps. I have worked with Icefaces (JSF2) and Ext JS in the front end and Spring, Hiberate, Ibatis in the backend.

Comment: Personally I am leaning towards Primefaces, Spring and Hibernate app but the client is a big oracle shop with lots of data driven (with millions of records in each table) legacy (oracle forms) apps which need to be modernized and they are inclined towards ADF framework.

Comment: Written a lot of Java, especially Spring since 2005.  By all means, so with what your client wants.  You'll guarantee a repeat engagement when they want all that mess ripped out again.